# How to sort a list of strings alphabetically in Python?

Tags: python

I have a list of strings in Python that I want to sort alphabetically. I've tried using the sorted() function, but it doesn't seem to be working. Here's an example of what I've tried:

```py
my_list = ['banana', 'apple', 'orange']
sorted_list = sorted(my_list)
print(sorted_list)
```

But the output I get is still the same as the original list:

```py
['banana', 'apple', 'orange']
```

What am I doing wrong? How can I sort my list of strings alphabetically?

Comment: When I run the code in your question I get `['apple', 'banana', 'orange']`. [Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K6gsycjPM/7/P7cyPiezuETBViFaPSkxDwjVdRTUEwsKclJBjPyixLz0VPVYruL8opLUFJhaCE8DqlmTq6AoM69EA0mN5v//AA "Python 3 – Try It Online")

Comment: Your list elements are strings. Therefore the built-in sort (either *sorted()* function or the *sort()* function of a list object) will perform lexicographical ordering. Your code does not match the output

Answer (score -2, accepted):

Code1:

```
  my_list = ['banana', 'apple', 'orange']
  my_list.sort()
  print(my_list)
  my_list = ['banana', 'apple', 'orange']
  my_list.sort()
```

Code 1 will give you output like [apple, banana, orange]
as .sort() simply sorts just like words are sorted in dictionary.

Code 2:

```
 my_list = ['banana', 'apple', 'orange']
 my_list.sort()
 newSortedList=[]
 for i in my_list:
     s="".join(sorted(i))
     newSortedList.append(s)
 print(newSortedList)
```

Code 2 will give output like ['aelpp', 'aaabnn', 'aegnor']
in code first i have sorted the list using .sort() which changes the my_list to:

[apple, banana, orange]

After which i have individually  sorted each string in list with sorted function which returns list of sorted character which will look like:

['a', 'e', 'l', 'p', 'p']

then using "".join() i have joined the list and final output is a string:

"aelpp"

which i have appended to newSortedList

The above is done for each string in List.

Hope this was helpful.

Comment: Sort does **not** operate on just the first character in a string

Comment: It's not an entirely accurate statement. If your statement was true then this list *['ab', 'aa']* would be considered already sorted

Comment: Yes, it is wrong. If the first characters of two strings are the same, it checks the second characters etc.

Answer (score -1):

Given the following list:

```
my_list = ['banana', 'apple', 'orange']
```

...you can create a new sorted list with:

```
sorted(my_list)
```

However, if you want your list sorted *in situ* then:

```
my_list.sort()
```

...is what you want